# Is it possible to use different Solr cores for different subtrees within a domain in TYPO3?

Tags: solr, typo3

Background: Our pagetree doesn't work with language overlays nor with seperate domains for each domain. The different languages are represented by subtrees below the domain.

Pagetree:

- example.com (Rootpage + sys_domain)

  - de

    - Seite 1
    - Seite 2
  - en

    - Page 1
    - Page 2

We're using TYPO3, EXT:solr and Solr.

**Is it possible to use different Solr cores for different subtrees within a domain in TYPO3?**

So far, I found a solution for handling different languages and cores based on TS-Conditions: [globalVar = GP:L = 1]. But that's not our use-case.

Further, I found a 6 years old question which exactly represents the use-case, but doesn't have a positive answer (https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/158570/).

Can somebody give me a hint? Is this use-case possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with version 7 of EXT:solr

- Set "Use as Rootpage" on page "de" and page "en"
- Remove "Use as Rootpage" on Rootpage, if set (if using EXT:realurl, make sure to set it in the configuration explicitly)
- Add the following lines to your AdditionalConfiguration.php

`

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['solr']['sites']['<uid of page "de">']['domains'] = ['your.domain.de'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['solr']['sites']['<uid of page "en">']['domains'] = ['your.domain.de'];
```

- Configure the cores on page "de" and "en" in TypoScript constants as you need it

`

```
plugin.tx_solr {
  solr {
    scheme = http
    host = <your-solr-dhost>
    port = 80
    path = <your-solr-core>
  }
}
```

Then you need to scheduler tasks to index the site ... one for "de" and one for "en".

Works pretty nice here :-)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it is most probably not possible.
The reason is, that EXT:solr tools need one common TypoScript configuration which works for both backend and frontend context at the same time.
That is why they choosed to evaluate the TypoScript configuration not based on a frontend request (which would make it possible to differ the configuration on any position in the page tree) but based on pages marked as domain roots.

So, the configuration parser looks for such pages first and then evaluates TypoScript setup at that specific level/point in the tree.

I think your only solution is to make rather deep changes to the machanism described above, which is possible and I made it myself (to exclude some root level pages because I had many of them).
This way you can probably instruct the engine to fetch the TypoScript setup from whatever fixed position in the tree you want.

If you are interested to try this, this will be the class method to extend: ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\ConnectionManager::getConfiguredSolrConnections()